# Exporting a text file in rails with the data in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, excel

I got some 5 field in my model named "Data" in a rails application say - Name, Age, Place, Country, Marks.

I want to get that data in an text file in the below format

```
Name : Lokesh
Age : "20"
place :xxx
country : yyyyyyy
marks : "90%"


Name : Ramesh
Age : "23"
place : aaa
country : zzzz
marks : "89.2%"
```

and so on..
How to generate this type of text file in rails.

If thats not possible(or difficult), I know how to export these data into an csv file. Please help me in converting these csv or excel file into a text file of the above format.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Thank you

Comment: What kind of help you want? Write code? Maybe some references for read? Have you tried something?

Comment: Where do you want the file? On the server? On the client? For file format, you might want to look up YAML, which is what your desired format resembles. There are a variety of gems that allow you to interact with YAML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this quickly would be to loop through your table and display this in the view in your browser.  Then just copy and paste it into a text file.

In your controller:

```
def some_method
    @records = Data.all
end
```

In the corresponding view:

```
<%  @records.each do |record| %>
  <ul>
    <li>Name: <%=record.name%></li>
    <li>Age : <%=record.agae%></li>
    <li>place: <%=record.place%></li>
    <li>country: <%=record.country%></li>
    <li>marks: <%=record.marks%></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```